Intuition of sign used for Lagrange multiplier and corresponding constraint function in constrained optimization
It seems that in many applications there may be some economic interpretation for the Lagrange multiplier and thus it might be beneficial to ensure it's value takes on a specific sign.
If the above is intended, then clearly the choice of sign for the multiplier in the Lagrangian should correspond to a choice of subtracting either the LHS or RHS in the constraint.
As an example, say we have an agent $i$ with quasilinear utility over two goods, $(c_1, c_2)$ who solves
\begin{align*}
&\max_{c_{i1}, c_{i2}} u_i(c_{i1}) + \beta c_{i2} \\
&\text{s.t.} \\
p_1c_{i1} + c_{i2} = &a_i
\end{align*}
The typically constructed Lagrangian would then be
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L} = u_i(c_{i1}) + \beta c_{i2} + \lambda_i(a_i - p_1 c_{i1} - c_{i2})
\end{align*}
Now we could also write this as
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L} = u_i(c_{i1}) + \beta c_{i2} - \lambda_i(p_1 c_{i1} + c_{i2} - a_i)
\end{align*}
and the signs in our first order conditions would be unchanged, that is
\begin{align*}
c_{i1}:& u_{i, c}(c_{i1}) = \lambda_i p_1 \\
c_{i2}:& \beta = \lambda_i
\end{align*}
Now say we chose one of the following constructions
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L} = u_i(c_{i1}) + \beta c_{i2} - \lambda_i(a_i - p_1 c_{i1} - c_{i2}) \\
\mathcal{L} = u_i(c_{i1}) + \beta c_{i2} + \lambda_i(p_1 c_{i1} + c_{i2} - a_i)
\end{align*}
which gives us first order conditions
\begin{align*}
c_{i1}:& u_{i, c}(c_{i1}) = -\lambda_i p_1 \\
c_{i2}:& \beta = -\lambda_i
\end{align*}
It seems the only difference here would be that $\lambda_i$ would take a negative value, given $\beta$ should be positive.
I guess my question is: how should we think about both our choice of signs for the Lagrange multiplier (i.e. whether we add or subtract the multiplier) in tandem with our construction of the constraint (i.e. whether we subtract the LHS or RHS from both sides of the constraint equation)? In the context of budget constraints I've seen the multiplier defined as a "shadow price", which to me would imply we desire a positive value for $\lambda_i$. So then how do we ensure this will play out when we initially construct the Lagrangian? Is it something like:
"If $f(x, y)$ is our objective function and $g(x, y) = c$ is our constraint, then the Lagrangian is either of form $\mathcal{L} = f(x, y) - \lambda(g(x, y) - c)$ or $\mathcal{L} = f(x, y) + \lambda(c - g(x, y))$" and that's it?

Dear hilard28, that Is all!

The Lagrange multiplier provides the "shadow price" of the constraint.
In the case where the Lagrangian takes the form:
$$
L = f(x,y) - \lambda(g(x,y) - c),
$$
then $\lambda$ measures the marginal change in the optimal value when $c$ increases by 1 unit. Note that we can rewrite:
$$
L = f(x,y) - \lambda g(x,y) + \lambda c.
$$
In the case where the Lagrangian takes the form:
$$
L = f(x,y) + \lambda(g(x,y) - c),
$$
The Lagrange multiplier simply switches sign. In this case $\lambda$ is the negative of the shadow price. Note that we can now rewrite:
$$
L = f(x,y) + \lambda g(x,y) - \lambda c.
$$
When I write down the Lagrangian, I simply make sure $\lambda$ is multiplied by $c$ (and not $-c$).
Note that in problems with equality constraints, shadow prices might be positive or negative depending on whether increasing $c$ increases or decreased the optimal value of the optimization problem. As such, there is no ex-ante restriction on its sign (safe from intuition). If you have inequality constraints (and Kuhn-Tucker conditions) the signs of the Lagrange multipliers are usually determined.

Dear tdm, c can increase not only in 1 unit

If Lagrange Theorem holds we have $\Delta f = \lambda _1 \cdot \epsilon _1+ \lambda _2 \cdot \epsilon _2+ \cdots + \lambda _m \cdot \epsilon _m$ so $\Delta f=\lambda _1+ \lambda _2 + \dots + \lambda _m $ whenever $\epsilon _j = 1$ with $\epsilon _j = \Delta c_j$

Let
$\mathbf x \in \mathbb{R^n} \quad \mathbf x= (x_1 , x_2 , \cdots , x_n ) $
$A$, $B$ $m$x$n$ matrix, $\mathbf b \in \mathbb{R^m}$, $\mathbf c \in \mathbb{R^m}$.
Let indicate with $< . , . >$ the dot product and with $\lambda= (\lambda_1 , \lambda_2 , \cdots , \lambda_m ) $, $\eta= (\eta_1 , \eta_2 , \cdots , \eta_m ) $  the Lagrange multipliers.
First case: min
$\min_{x\in \mathit{ \Omega }} f(\mathbf x) $
$ \Omega$ defined by
$ \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\begin{matrix} A \cdot \mathbf x \ge \mathbf b \end{matrix} \\
\begin{matrix} B \cdot \mathbf x \le \mathbf c \end{matrix} \\
\mathbf x \ge \mathbf 0 \\
\end{array} \right.$
Lagrangian function
$\mathcal{L}(\mathbf x, \lambda, \eta)= f(\mathbf x) - < \lambda, A \cdot \mathbf x - \mathbf b > +  < \eta , B \cdot \mathbf x - \mathbf c >$
Second case: max
$\max_{x\in \mathit{ \Omega }} f(\mathbf x) $
$ \Omega$ defined by
$ \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\begin{matrix} A \cdot \mathbf x \le \mathbf b \end{matrix} \\
\begin{matrix} B \cdot \mathbf x \ge \mathbf c \end{matrix} \\
\mathbf x \ge \mathbf 0 \\
\end{array} \right.$
Lagrangian function
$\mathcal{L}(\mathbf x, \lambda, \eta)= f(\mathbf x) - < \lambda, A \cdot \mathbf x - \mathbf b > +  < \eta , B \cdot \mathbf x - \mathbf c >$
Example
$\max_{x\in \mathit{ \Omega }} f(\mathbf x) $; $ \Omega$ defined by: $<\mathbf a_1^t,\mathbf x>=b_1$
Lagrangian function:
$\mathcal{L}(\mathbf x, \lambda_1)= f(\mathbf x)+< \lambda_1, b_1 - \mathbf a^t_1 \cdot \mathbf x >$
